# First Flutter App error: cannot resolve symbol "Properties"

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter

I followed the steps in the Flutter document and tried to build my first Flutter app in Intellij IDEA. And when I try to run it,there was an error about my JAVA_HOME variable. And an error about cannot resolve symbol "Properties" in the build.gradle file. I really don't know what to do.

This is my error information displayed in the Console window.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Finished with error: ProcessException: Process 
"F:\untitled\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: F:\Google download\jdk- 
10.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
  Command: F:\untitled\android\gradlew.bat -v
```

Actually there is nothing wrong with my JAVA_HOME variable, I set it to the proper directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131.

And I run the command it shows above "F:\untitled\android\gradlew.bat -v", it seemed to update the gradle version, but the error didn't resolved.

And this is the code in build.gradle file.

```
def localProperties = new Properties() 
//there will be a highlight on Properties indicates that 'cannot resolve symbol "Properties" '

def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
//the same as the Properties on GradleException
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.untitled"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I just upgraded Flutter and have the same issues with the Properties and GradleException in my app level build.gradle file. I'm using Android Studio though. Adding maven repository didn't fix it for me.

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html

Just check where you have your JDK installed, and follow as the above link

Answer (score 180):

> This issue is due to not pointing to correct Android API Platform

**Solution :**

In the Android Studio
File > Project Structure

1. Now a window pops up
2. Within that select **Project Settings/Project**
3. Make sure Project SDK is set to latest platform as mentioned in the pic below

[image]

4. Next select **Project Settings/Modules** sub tab
5. There select the lastest Android SDK as you did in step-3

[image]

6. Finally replace the **GradleException()** with **FileNotFoundException()** as mentioned below

[image]

Comment: If anyone wants a video link to this issue https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJp14BeTjAs

Comment: In Android studio 4.1, I cannot find the Project Structure setting........Can anyone guide me?

Comment: @DharmikThakkar You Can Find Project Structure settings in file tab.

Comment: This is the best solution and very straightforward, thanks!

Comment: I followed this and still doesnt work. The word `new` still causes issues. Even removing it didnt help

Comment: Thanks! it seems to be working fine, just tested it.

Comment: I followed this and worked like a charm.

Comment: why is it complicated like heck? tried everythng, errors in build.gradle do not go away, and git commit and push analyzer warnings must be overridden with "push anyway" to get it done

Answer (score 103):

I tried all other suggestions, and they did not help. Then I have removed "new" in front of GradleException, and it solved the problem:

```
throw GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
```

It worked perfectly fine with the "new" word for a long time. I don't know what have caused this change.

Comment: FYI, rather than removing new, Go to ***file*** then ***Invalidate Chache / Restart***, that should do the trick.

Comment: @Nick FYI Invalidating the cache seem to have fixed the issue for few minutes and it started showing as error again. I ended up removing `new`.

Answer (score 28):

I've just had this issue and in my case was due to an invalid SDK configuration.
I've solved by going to:

> Project structure > Project Settings > Modules > Module SDK

and switching from `<no project SDk>`

to `Android api 29 platform`

Comment: No change for me.

Comment: I created another app and Replaced all the .dart file and pubspec.yaml. It is the fastest method I found.

Answer (score 20):

Go to `File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Select your project -> apply your API`

[image]

Answer (score 9):

For me just deleting new before Properties and GradleException it have solved it.

```
• Flutter version 1.21.0-10.0.pre.55 | Master Channel |
• Dart version 2.10.0 (build 2.10.0-11.0.dev)
• Android Studio 4.0.1
```

here is first lines in build.gradle 'contains changes'

```
def localProperties = Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}
```

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

Answer (score 5):

> Cannot resolve symbol 'Properties'
>  Cannot resolve symbol
> 'GradleException'

or even in the case of many errors on opening manifest file.

It's not an issue, you don't need to do anything. These are shown because IDE didn't detect them in the normal mode. Just 'Open for Editing in Android Studio' (you may find it on TOP-RIGHT) then Select 'New Window', you will find everything well.

Answer (score 4):

Need to include google maven repository to your project level build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {                                    //add this section 
            url "https://maven.google.com"           
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's working for me:

1. **File > Project Structure (Command + ;) > Under Project Settings/Project > Set Project SDK to Android API 29 Platform**
2. There should be a notification stating there is an invalid item in the dependencies list under Project Structure/Problems. If there is, go to **Project Structure > Under Project Settings/Modules > select app_name_android > Dependencies tab > choose the latest "Android API 29 Platform" in the Module SDK box.**
3. Update `GradleException()` to `FileNotFoundException()` under android/app/build_gradle since it's not supported in the Java version of Android API 29
   [Solution found](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29608)

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me(android studio version: 4.1, flutter version: 2.5)

1. Open pubspec.yaml -> run "pub get", now
2. Go to File -> Invalidate Chache / Restart

Answer (score 2):

Yes, i follow this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37391#issuecomment-544823712 and i change GraddleException to FileNotFoundException in android/app/build.gradle.
Otherwise upgrade kotlin version in android/build.gradle to 1.3.50.
At least, upgrade gradle distributionUrl to version 5.4.1

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is it an answer? Please edit it to clear.

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem. I get this error because I edit android module without open it first using AS in another tab (Tools -> Flutter -> Open Android module..). Then I have a solution, just restart and kill the chache in your Android Studio (File -> Invalidate Chache / Restart).

It fixed for me, I hope you too

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29608#issuecomment-528243662

Answer (score 2):

It's not an error, don't remove new keywords from GradleException and properties() method just restart your android studio your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in Android Studio. It looks like a bug with the Flutter Plugin so it's pretty likely it's a problem in Intellij too. In Android Studio there is a link to "Open for Editing in Android Studio" (top right). When I click that I see there are no longer any issues highlighted. I would check for a similar link in IntelliJ. Here is the Flutter issue where I learned of this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37391.

Answer (score 1):

In yours "project\android\build.gradle"
Just change:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
```

to:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to flutter documentation
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/android-studio#android-ide

Opening the root directory of a Flutter project doesn’t expose all the Android files to the IDE. Flutter apps contain a subdirectory named android. If you open this subdirectory as its own separate project in Android Studio, the IDE will be able to fully support editing and refactoring all Android files (like Gradle scripts).

Answer (score 0):

Update: Oct. 15, 2020.

I am running Flutter Version 1.12.13+hotfix9 in Android Studio Version 4.1 (re-installed today) with runtime version 1.8.0_242-release-1644.... on Windows 10, amd64.

I repaired both the project level and app level gradle build files by removing the word 'new' before 'Properties'  and 'GradleException' and in both files the Studio error messages were removed.

Comment: This is just [reaffirming a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63438755/3025856). Please upvote existing answers instead of reiterating them. The only difference is the specific version, which I'd only expect to be relevant if the behavior _changed_ with that specific version.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's because of invalid file

> pubspec.yaml

Please re-check the file configurations.

Answer (score 0):

may be your current flutter version is higher than that specified in  pubspec.yaml:
Change these line to be lower or equal to your current version

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.10"
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all click on file section then
[file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTMm5.png)

after in that we have project structure section
[click on the project  structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op1oH.png)
after that go to project in that and change the project sdk to latest if its null or its outdated , as I have updated mine to 30

[project sdk to change here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yadov.png) 
change the sdk if necessary and apply the changes
after that go to problems which is beneath project if it shows some error just fix it with a tap as you can see mine[fix it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/filnN.png)
after that go to app/build.gradle then change the GradleException to FileNOtFoundExcetion Now you are good to go after saving all errors will be vanish[FileNotFoundException changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9XKn.png)