# Flutter error - Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm new to flutter. I just created a new project in flutter and have not even altered the code.
And when I run the code I get the following error.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM A750F in debug mode...
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I have no idea how to fix this, searched a number of ways

When I run flutter doctor I get this error,

```
Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

I dont know if this has got anything to do with the error above.

build.gradle(app)

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.dev.teamo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: share your build.gradle app level

Comment: try the solution in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/60565001/14354980

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find a perfect solution for this.
I solved it by **resetting** my windows. All licenses are now accepted and the app runs fine.

Answer (score 2):

You need to accept the licenes from Android to run the app:

run: 
`flutter doctor --android-licenses`

And accept the terms on the terminal

Comment: I've done that.. still it is showing that license status unknown

Comment: when i run the command it says 4 license are not accepted and asks if u want to accept.. but doesnt wait to take the input `y`... It directly exits from the task.. i could only accept it using this command `/path-sdk-/tools/bin --licenses`

Answer (score 2):

I tried this as coined from [here](https://nabil6391.medium.com/solutions-to-flutter-error-gradle-task-assembledebug-failed-with-exit-code-1-1d2c36b2001a) since I couldn't get it to work from all methods:

- in `root/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` set
  `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip`
- in `root/android/build.gradle`, set
  `dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2' }`
- check if in `root/android/app/build.gradle` SDK version is set to minimum 28 for:
  `compileSdkVersion 28` and `targetSdkVersion 28`

My project successfully built after doing this

Answer (score 2):

Delete the **.gradle** folder then re-run `flutter run`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way it actually worked for me:
1- visit gradle releases webpage and download last version of gradle
2- unzip the file in this path : "C:\Users"pc name".gradle\wrapper\dists
3- open your editor and try again and it will work inshaalah ☺