# Unpack a list in dart

Tags: list, dart

I build some lists (seed), containing random integers I chose. I saved them in a 2-Dimensional list. Now I want to concatenated them as a 1-Dimensional list.
How should I unpack the list?
Is there a build in function or a shortcut to unpack lists?

code below

```dart
  List<int> _getOperatorList() {
    const List<List<int>> seed = [
      [0, 1, 2, 3],
      [3, 2, 1, 0],
      [0, 1, 0, 2],
      [1, 3, 1, 0],
      [2, 1, 2, 2],
      [3, 0, 3, 2],
    ];
    Random random = Random();
    List<int> randomInts = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
      randomInts.add(seed[random.nextInt(seed.length)].);
    }
    return randomInts;
  }
```

Comment: how about you share the build.gradle file , and telling what gradle version your using would be helpful .

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56938436/first-flutter-app-error-cannot-resolve-symbol-properties).

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
void main() {
  const List<List<int>> seed = [
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [3, 2, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 2],
    [1, 3, 1, 0],
    [2, 1, 2, 2],
    [3, 0, 3, 2],
  ];
  
  print(seed.expand((e) => e).toList());
}
```

prints `[0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 3, 2]`

Comment: thank you this makes my code a hell lot simpler

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can do it.

1. There is a shortcut for unpacking a list it is the three dots in front of the list. for example ...[3,5,6,2], will unpack it.

So you can write like this :

```
void main() {
  const List<List<int>> seed = [
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [3, 2, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 2],
    [1, 3, 1, 0],
    [2, 1, 2, 2],
    [3, 0, 3, 2],
  ];
  var singleSeed = [];

  seed.map(
    (element) {
      singleSeed = [...singleSeed, ...element];
    },
  ).toList();
  
  print(singleSeed);
}
```

2. The other way is using the `expand()` method that returns a one array list like this :

```
void main() {

    const List<List<int>> seed = [
     [0, 1, 2, 3],
     [3, 2, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 2],
     [1, 3, 1, 0],
     [2, 1, 2, 2],
     [3, 0, 3, 2],
    ];
    var singleSeed = seed.expand((element) => element).toList();
    print(singleSeed);
}
```

Both ways are good, up to you to choose.