# Flutter run is working from terminal, but error from VSCode (F5)

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Flutter run is working from terminal, but error from VSCode (F5), error message :

> What went wrong:
> A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'compileSdkVersion' for extension 'flutter' of type >FlutterExtension.

> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to >get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Any suggestions how to validate my application? What can case such a problem?

Thank you

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. Ran gradlew clean build, flutter clean, flutter doctor. 
I'm using these versions:
flutter 2.10.3
andoid api 31
kotlin 1.5.31
gradle 7.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I don't completely know what project or process you are working on, I simply checked the error.

The commands `flutter clean`, `flutter upgrade` may help. Seems like it is related to JDK17. You can look at this:[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56938436/first-flutter-app-error-cannot-resolve-symbol-properties/60565001#60565001)for more information, there are all kinds of situation.

Comment: Did this command work? Are there any updates?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command on your console
"flutter clean"
"flutter pub get"
"flutter run"