# I am new in flutter and trying to change my app icon with Flutter Launcher Icons and getting error 'ERROR: InvalidConfigException' how i can fix this?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[pubspec.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLPNb.png)

[pubspec.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQniV.png)

[icon location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr1Ls.png)

[How I fix this error??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXaiM.png)

Comment: According error you have to set minSdk version in Android https://prnt.sc/E3q_oZgMMnUg

Comment: android/app/build.gradle set minSdkVersion. May solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do following:

Goto `projectroot/android/app/build.gradle` file

inside `andorid` tag inside that `defaultConfig` tag you can write this

[image]

```
minSdk   17
```

then after you can check by `flutter clean` and `flutter pub ge`t and run again.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but still same error

Comment: Thanks for replying, but still same error...after adding minSdk 17, I got error in build.gradle. After removing minSdk 17 it shows error of build.gradle: 1)Cannot resolve symbol 'Properties' 2)Cannot resolve symbol 'GradleException'. how i fix this new error??

Comment: please check this for  Properties : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56938436/first-flutter-app-error-cannot-resolve-symbol-properties